# Display a formatted timestamp in template

Tags: node.js, meteor

How do i format a timestamp inside the template? I followed a tutorial on building a chat and it works. Now i expanded the chat with some features like deleting the message and putting the time in front of the message. But when i write `{{timestamp}}` inside the template a UNIX timestamp is being given. How do i format it to show time like '6:12'. The timestamp is being stored in a Messages collection.

Is the right place to manipulate the timestamp inside of the

`Template.Messages.created = function ( ) { ... }`

function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) and the [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

Comment: Template.Messages.helpers seems to be the right place then :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Although not essential in this case, I would recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/milliseconds-since-the-unix-epoch/), it makes working with dates and times in Javascript a breeze.

You can install the package from Atmosphere or download the [script](https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/1.7.0/min/moment.min.js) into your `client` dir then use a helper similar to the one below:-

```
Template.Messages.helpers({
    created: function() { 
        var time = moment(this.timestamp);
        return time.format('h:mm a');
    }
});
```

*NB:* I've assumed `timestamp` is a var on the context object.

Answer (score 1):

I use this library. It gives you all the date formatting you will ever need.  With meteor just drop it in and you can use it in any helper to return the formatted date.

http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid libraries and manipulate with Javascript Date object I would suggest (this assumes that date is in ISO format 2010-06-15T00:00:00, wich you can get from Date.toISOString()):

Implement format method (thanks [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)), put it in i.e. lib/utils.js:

```
String.prototype.format = function(args, index) {
  return this.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(match, number) {
    return typeof args[index[number]] != 'undefined'
      ? args[index[number]]
      : match
    ;
  });
};
```

Create helper (put it into client/client.js)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('formatDate',function(input, pattern){
    var iso = /^(\d{4})(?:-?W(\d+)(?:-?(\d+)D?)?|(?:-(\d+))?-(\d+))(?:[T ](\d+):(\d+)(?::(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?)?)?(?:Z(-?\d*))?$/;
    if(this[input]) {
        var parts = this[input].match(iso);
             return pattern.format(parts, {yyyy:1,MM:4,dd:5,hh:6,mm:7,ss:8,SSS:9});
        }
    return this[input];
});
```

Use the helper:

```
{{#each logs}}
   <tr>
      <td>{{formatDate 'ts' '{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this package [swag](https://github.com/elving/swag) which offers lots of useful handlebars helpers.

Checkout its date/time helpers: https://github.com/elving/swag#dates

You can format date/time as easily like:

```
var date = new Date()


{{formatDate date "%m/%d/%Y"}}
{{formatDate date "%I:%M%p"}}
{{formatDate date "%F"}}
{{formatDate date "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z"}}

07/26/2015
11:38PM
2015-08-28
20150828T233805-0004
```